Google Play Console warning "Multiple clickable items share this location on the screen." for SupportMapFragment map
I've encountered a warning from Google Play Console when uploading my app:
"There are multiple clickable elements in this screen area. Element path - id/map."
I have an activity with a SupportMapFragment displaying a Google map. I've removed all other objects, leaving only the standard code provided by Google for the map setup. In the XML layout, there are no other visible or clickable elements that could overlap with the map.
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private ActivityMapsBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = ActivityMapsBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="false"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity" />

Despite these efforts, Google Play Console keeps showing this warning.And is there a way to resolve it?

Added android:clickable="false" to the SupportMapFragment in XML.

